# How to build customized FormBuilderField that returns list of map

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-form-builder

The idea is simply to retreive a list of data from the backend, and the user has to submit quantities (it's like calling purchase order quotation from back end then choose delivried quantites) as follow :

[image]

I created the card widget and here is the code :

```
class FormListCard extends StatelessWidget {
  String title;
  String subTitle;
  KTextField field;

  FormListCard(
      {required this.title, required this.subTitle, required this.field});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool isLandScape =
        MediaQuery.of(context).orientation == Orientation.landscape;
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        const Divider(),
        Row(
          children: [
            Text(
              title,
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: isLandScape ? 18.sp : 32.sp,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
            ),
            const Spacer(),
            textInput(isLandScape),
            SizedBox(
              width: 20.w,
            ),
            Text(
              subTitle,
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: isLandScape ? 18.sp : 32.sp,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
            )
          ],
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget textInput(bool isLandScape) {
    return SizedBox(
        width: isLandScape ? 150.w : 300.w,
        height: isLandScape ? 150.h : 80.h,
        child: field);
  }
}
```

But i couldn't acheive to create the customized FormBuilderField, any idea how to acheive this ?